# How to convert DataFrame columns to float and permanently keep it that way

Tags: pandas, dataframe

So I was successfully able to change the strings to float, but I want it to permanently stay that way, something like a inplace=True. However, I wasn't able to do the inplace=True and receive an error when I try. Basically I want to see the changes kept in place when I do nba.head().

I would appreciate all help :).

```
nba[["G","GS","MP"]] = nba[["G","GS","MP"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your line code?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
nba[["G","GS","MP"]] = nba[["G","GS","MP"]].astype(float)
```